# Javascript: recursively Fetch data to populate html text

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api, async.js

Disclaimer: This is my first question, and I am new to JavaScript.

I am attempting to populate some html text elements by fetching data using an API. This API returns a JSON object with some of the text I need, but also with some API URLs I need to then fetch additional data from. Some of these URLs are held in arrays. So, I need to fetch a JSON object, iterate through it while sometimes storing strings and sometimes fetching additional JSONs that hold the remainder of the text I need. I am having a lot of trouble dealing with promises and the asynchronous execution. I don't know how to wait for a promise to be completed, so the returned data keeps coming up undefined.

```
async function GetData(address) {
    const response = await fetch(address);
    const json = await response.json();
    return json;
}
async function CleanData(origData) {
    Object.entries(origData).forEach(async ([key,value]) => {
        // look for arrays
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            value.forEach(async (element, i) => {
                // look for links inside arrays
                if (element.indexOf("https") != -1) {
                    let newData = await GetData(element);
                    // replace link with name or title
                    if (newData["name"] !== undefined) {
                        origData[key][i] = newData["name"]
                    } else if (newData["title"] !== undefined) {
                        origData[key][i] = newData["title"];
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        // look for links and replace with name
        if (value.indexOf("https") != -1) {
            let newData = await GetData(value);
            origData[key] = newData["name"];
        }
    })
    return origData;
}
function PopulateFields(fieldData) {
    nameId.innerText = fieldData["name"];
    valueIds.forEach(node => {
        const nodeId = node.id;
        node.innerText = fieldData[nodeId];
    });
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener(
"click", async () => {               // also tried without async using .then()
    let data = await GetData(ApiUrl);
    data = await CleanData(data);           
    PopulateFields(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to normal loops (`for...of`) instead of forEach. It will likely solve all your problems. There's never a good reason to use forEach, it's just a holdover from the jQuery days.

The issue now is that you pass async functions to `forEach()`, but there's no way to await *those*. By using regular loops you can just await inside the loop and the 'correct' thing will happen.